# Javascript not parsing array passed over through function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, cypress

I have an array which is passed through a function using javascript, I can't see anything wrong with the code but it doesn't pass over the first array correctly so it can be parsed.

The idea is the first array is 56 items, it then calls the parseData function which is supposed to split this array into chunks of 7.

Here is the two functions:

```
static async validateRowValues() {
    let data = [];
    await cy.get('tr > td > div.dlCell')
      .each(function (row) {
          let d = row.get(0).innerText;
          data.push(d);
      });
    console.log(data);

    let response = await this.parseData(data);

    console.log({response});
}

static async parseData(tData) {
    console.log(tData);
    let array = [];
    let coll_array = [];
    debugger;
    await tData.forEach(async (v, index) => {
        await array.push(v);
        if (index % 6 === 0 && index !== 0) {
            await coll_array.push(array);
            array = [];
        }
    });
    return coll_array;
}
```

The first console.log within parseData does return the 56 items, however by the time it reaches tData.forEach it has completely lost its data, and the parsing returns an empty array when it returns coll_array.

If anyone has any ideas?

Comment: NB: I have no experience with cypress, but I don't understand why your second function is `async` and has `await` inside. All those actions are clearly synchronous, so not really something for `async/await`.

Comment: I've tried adjusting the code to make the second function not async/await but still has no reflection on the outcome of the parse.

Comment: Also, your first function doesn't return anything. Is that intended? Is that function relevant for the question you ask? I mean: you could (for debugging purposes) just initialise `tData` to some hardcoded array as the first line in `parseData`. Do you then still have the problem?

Comment: interesting thing is.. you type the code above into the console of the web browser and bang... it works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have resolved this. 
It turns out everything in Cypress is a promise so the first function needed to have a .then

```
 static async validateRowValues() {
    let data = [];
    await cy.get('tr > td > div.dlCell')
      .each(function (row) {
          let d = row.get(0).innerText;
          data.push(d);
      }).then(() => {
        this.parseData(data);
      });  
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much a misuse of `cy.get()`.

Comment: It's kind of hard to know where to begin. The purpose of a `cy.get()` is to test DOM elements, but there does not seem to be any tests there. It works because Cypress has a built-in jquery-lite, but if you used jquery or even `document.querySelectorAll()` instead you would likely eliminate the async nature of the function.

Comment: If someone else has to modify or maintain this in the future they are going to spend quite a bit of time figuring it out. The parsing code should be separated from the testing code if you want to create a well-formed test suite.

Comment: I completely understand what you’re saying however the functionality is working fine now. Also we would like to keep the test framework consistent and use cy to interact with DOM elements and also use them to test, we didn’t feel it necessary to interact with a specific div element using document when the elements before it are being queried with cy itself.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, I mainly wanted to raise red flag in case someone else copies this.

Comment: Can I also ask, does it work without the `async / await`, they appear to be unnecessary.

Comment: @eric99 the parsing code is separated out, the was an initial starting point to achieve the functionality we needed, I appreciate your input I really do but I don’t know why a simple question which we found an answer, have gone away and refactored has turned into you making assumptions around our test suite?

Comment: @eric99 works without which we refactored this afternoon. Just been busy so not updated the answer

Comment: I also believe nobody should ever copy anything from here, they should take ideas and adapt to their own scenario

Answer (score 1):

As of now I will take it you getting your data fine in array.
ex. arr = [1,2,3,.....58]

Use below code to split in chunks of 7

```
arr = arr.reduce((acc,data,index)=>{
  if(index==0 || index%7==0) acc.push([])
  acc[acc.length-1].push(data)
  return acc
},[])
```

The above code will return

```
arr = [ [1,..,7], [8,...14], ....]
```